# Switching between highlightjs styles

Tags: angular7, highlightjs

In my component I let the user switch between color themes (dark/light).
Based on what the user selects I want to be able to switch between highlightjs styles (vs.css / atom-one-dark.css')
Is there a way to do it without having to modify the library's styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own custom css file combining everything I needed.